# google app engine supports restful API with Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

does google app engine supports restful API with Java?
How to create a RESTful API using Google App Engine with Java?

Answer (score 5):

One year ago, I started to learn Google App Engine and Google end Point.

Thoses links help me a lot:

**Google Datastore (NoSQL) + Endpoints (Android):**
 https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

**Google end point (Amazing links):**
http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/

**RestFull Syntax (Sorry it's in French):** 
http://blog.xebia.fr/2014/06/23/google-app-engine-cloud-endpoint-creer-notre-api-v2-et-lutiliser-avec-angularjs/

**App Engine :** 
http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/02/17/downloading-and-uploading-data-on-google-app-engine-using-java-application/

**Officials docs:**
Datastore:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/?hl=fr
Endpoints:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/?hl=fr
AppEngine:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs?hl=fr

Hope Thoses links help you !

Comment: does google app engine endpoints API & RESTful API both are same?

Comment: Yes the operation is the same. But I advise you to use the google api, as you can read here: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/

Comment: If both are same then how can I implement HATEOAS in google endpoints?

Comment: You can and it'll works ! But if you want later, use authentication with google credential, it will be very very difficult  (personnal experiences)

Comment: But if you want implement HATEOAS, you have to build servlet in app engine, not API Backend.. So it's more difficult !

Comment: thanks @Phil, one more question is jersey or restlet necessary for writing google endpoints API?

Comment: Both will work, but only with servlet (AppEngine). Google endpoint libs will work only with API Backend.

Comment: I am confused, when should I use jersey?

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong. I thought that Jersey was a Rest Client.. I don't personnaly implement it in App Engine.. But that guy yes: http://blog.sortedset.com/googles-app-engine-java/google-app-engine-jax-rs-jersey/

Comment: yes I have seen many questions on stackoverflow they used jersey with google endpoints don't know why?

Comment: No I don't know.. But use Google API for endpoints, it's really better than your on API (HTTPS an credentials).

Comment: Jersey is the reference implementation of the JAX-RS API for doing RESTful webservices in Java; thus using Jersey you can build both a client and a server. But its just one of many possible choices, Google likely has its own built-in.

Comment: thanks Gimby, should I use jersey for writing endpoints API?